# How to compare two routes by hand

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can I **manually** (programmatically) compare two routes and find out if they are same? (if `router-link-active` or `router-link-exact-active` would be present)

Generally i need this sort of a function

```
/* 
   @params route1, route2 : Route
*/
function isActivated(route1, route2) {
  /* comparing them somehow */
  return {
    exactActive,
    active
  };
}
```

**Use Case:**
I have a `NestedLink.vue` component which is wrapper over `router-link`.
It takes `to` prop just as `router-link` (and passes it down to child router-link). If current route is active, nested links will apear nearby.

**My approach**:

```
function isActivated(route1, route2) {
  if (
    route1.matched.some(record =>
      record.regex.test(route2.fullPath)
    )
  ) {
    return { exactActive: true };
  }
  return { exactActive: false };
}
```

It may tell when routes are `exact-active` but not for `not-exact-active`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code, used inside router-link component.

```
const START = '/';
const trailingSlashRE = /\/?$/;

function isObjectEqual (a, b) {
  if ( a === void 0 ) a = {};
  if ( b === void 0 ) b = {};

  // handle null value #1566
  if (!a || !b) { return a === b }
  var aKeys = Object.keys(a);
  var bKeys = Object.keys(b);
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) {
    return false
  }
  return aKeys.every(function (key) {
    var aVal = a[key];
    var bVal = b[key];
    // check nested equality
    if (typeof aVal === 'object' && typeof bVal === 'object') {
      return isObjectEqual(aVal, bVal)
    }
    return String(aVal) === String(bVal)
  })
}

function isSameRoute (a, b) {
  if (b === START) {
    return a === b
  } else if (!b) {
    return false
  } else if (a.path && b.path) {
    return (
      a.path.replace(trailingSlashRE, '') === b.path.replace(trailingSlashRE, '') &&
      a.hash === b.hash &&
      isObjectEqual(a.query, b.query)
    )
  } else if (a.name && b.name) {
    return (
      a.name === b.name &&
      a.hash === b.hash &&
      isObjectEqual(a.query, b.query) &&
      isObjectEqual(a.params, b.params)
    )
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

**So, here's how to use it inside component:**

```
// OR JUST A STRING '/home'
let link = { name: 'home' } 
// will return true of false
let result = isSameRoute(this.$router.resolve(link).resolved, this.$route)
```